# Ayuda con inserción de fecha en SQLite y consulta

Tags: android, sqlite, date

les pido ayuda con este codigo, les doy una breve explicación, es en código de Android.
Intento ingresar una fecha String en una base de datos que tiene un campo fecha tambien TEXT (Activity2)

```js
package com.example.erickcr.discurso;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Bundle bolsaR;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5;
    EditText fecha;
    Button btn_sav;
    int año, mes, dia, d31;
    static final int TIPO_DIALOGO=0;
    static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener oyenteSelectorFecha;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        tv1= findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2= findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3= findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv4= findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        tv5= findViewById(R.id.tv5);


        btn_sav=findViewById(R.id.btn_sav);
        ////////////cuadro de fecha
        fecha=findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        Calendar calendario=Calendar.getInstance();
        dia=calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes=calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        año=calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        mostrarfecha();
        oyenteSelectorFecha=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                dia=dayOfMonth;
                mes=month;
                año=year;
                mostrarfecha();
            }
        };
         bolsaR=getIntent().getExtras();
        String DB_NAME = "db_mainero";

        bdayuda usbd=new bdayuda(this,DB_NAME,null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db=usbd.getReadableDatabase();

        tv1.setText(bolsaR.getString("can"));
        String[] n2= new String[]{(bolsaR.getString("can"))};

        Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT cancion,base FROM canciones WHERE _id=?",n2);
        if(c1.moveToFirst()){
            String can1=c1.getString(0);
            String can2=c1.getString(1);
            String can3=can1+"\n"+can2;
            tv2.setText(can3);}
        String[] n1= new String[]{(bolsaR.getString("dis"))};

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT discurso FROM discursos WHERE _id=?",n1);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            String datos=c.getString(0);
            tv5.setText(datos);}
        db.close();

        tv3.setText(bolsaR.getString("nom"));
        tv4.setText(bolsaR.getString("con"));
        fecha.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        btn_sav.setEnabled(true);

    }

    public void mostrarfecha(){
        fecha.setText(año+"-"+(mes+1)+"-"+dia);
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id){
            case 0:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,oyenteSelectorFecha,año,mes,dia);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void mostrarcalendario(View control){
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
    }

    public void historial(View control){
        String DB_NAME = "db_mainero";
        bdayuda usbd=new bdayuda(this,DB_NAME,null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db=usbd.getWritableDatabase();

        String d1=fecha.getText().toString();
        String d2=tv3.getText().toString();
        String d3=bolsaR.getString("dis");
        d31= Integer.parseInt(d3);
        String d4=tv4.getText().toString();
        String d5=bolsaR.getString("can");


        try{//Quite las comillas sencillas del d31
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO historia (fecha, hno, n_disc, cong, n_can)"+"VALUES ('"+d1+"','"+d2+"',"+d31+",'"+d4+"','"+d5+"')");
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, d1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btn_sav.setEnabled(false);}
        catch (SQLiteException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Sin embargo, en la otra actividad hago la consulta de los datos de la base, trato de sacar todos los datos pero ordenados por la fecha, pero no me aparecen asi me aparecen desordenados, tal vez algo hice mal, agradezco su ayuda y apoyo.

Actividad 12

```js
package com.example.erickcr.discurso;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Activity12 extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_12);
        lv=findViewById(R.id.lv);

        bdayuda usdb=new bdayuda(this,"db_mainero",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db=usdb.getWritableDatabase();


        lv=findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM historia ORDER BY date(fecha) DESC limit 1", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                item.add(c.getString(1)+" Hno: "+c.getString(2)+" Disc.: "+c.getString(3)+" Cong.: "+c.getString(4));
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void borrar_tab(View control){
        bdayuda usdb=new bdayuda(this,"db_mainero",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db=usdb.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("historia",null,null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Historial eliminado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.close();
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la respuesta, no estaba dandole el formato correcto para mandarlo al editText, solo  corregi la actvity2 de la siguiente manera:

```
public void mostrarfecha(){
    if ((mes+1)>9){
        if (dia<10){
        fecha.setText(año+"-"+(mes+1)+"-0"+dia);}
        else {
            fecha.setText(año+"-"+(mes+1)+"-"+dia);
            }

    } else {
        if (dia<10){
            fecha.setText(año+"-0"+(mes+1)+"-0"+dia);}
        else {
            fecha.setText(año+"-0"+(mes+1)+"-"+dia);
        }
    }


}
```